# Visual Studio and its enhancements

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Maybe this is one of those "Lazy" questions.

If there is an answer, I can use the saved time for some other useful thing.

Visual Studio has changed a lot, there are lots of useful plugins and addons but, is there anything  that can help me in this respect.

I am running application code from Visual Studio. I can see the UI, is there any way to see the code behind for what the UI is doing now?

If the UI is big, how can I determine where I need to put breakpoints?

Comment: I really have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: It is called the interactive debugger, where you can tell it to stop on the next statement.

Comment: What!?...This makes no sense?

Comment: This is a lazy question but not because of what you are asking, thats the good kind of lazy. Its lazy because your grammer, punctuation and style of prose make it barely comprehensable.

Comment: I've had a go at translating for you. I hope this is what you were asking.

Comment: You can try pressing Ctrl+Break

Answer (score 3):

You **probabbly** are searching  for http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16481/NET-Object-Spy-and-InvokeRemote. Very usefull tool for listening the events and see properties from UI of Widnows Forms applicaiton. More or less like "old, good" *Spy+* does.

[image]